# Applying JSON.parse() to unusual JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, meteor

Trying to access the value field of this JSON file using JSON.parse() in Meteor, but I cannot get it to return anything.  I suspect there is an error in my syntax in selecting the data from the imported JS object.

```
{"status":"success","data":{"subjects":[{"value":"ABC","descr":"Descriptions"}]},"message":null,"meta":{"copyright":"Copyright","referenceDttm":"Date"}}
```

I'm trying to store it into an array, subjectArray.  This is the code I'm using:

```
var subjectArray = new Array();
subjectFile = HTTP.get("https://classes.cornell.edu/api/2.0/config/subjects.json?roster=FA15");
subjectJSON = JSON.parse(subjectFile);
for (int i=0; i<subjectJSON.length; i++) {
  subjectArray.push(subjectJSON[i].value)
}
```

Pretty printed this is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "subjects": [
            {
                "descr": "Descriptions",
                "value": "ABC"
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": null,
    "meta": {
        "copyright": "Copyright",
        "referenceDttm": "Date"
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: First suggestion is properly format your code. Check the formatting help if needed.

Comment: loots like valid JSON to me.

Comment: and jsonlint agrees. please post your code.

Comment: [It works. What's the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net/91az8ttj/)

Comment: Sorry, I added my code

Comment: I'm pretty sure `HTTP.get()` is asynchronous. In which case this is a duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Responses from HTTP calls can take a while to come back so you should read your replies in an async way. You should move all of your code related to the "get" inside a callback function. If you want to find out more about HTTP and callbacks in Meteor make sure you check [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call)

If you know what "value" is in your for loop ('cause I don't), then this is your answer:

```
HTTP.get("https://classes.cornell.edu/api/2.0/config/subjects.json?roster=FA15", function (err, res) {
  if(!!err) return false; 
  subjectJSON = JSON.parse(res);
  for (var i = 0; i < subjectJSON.length; i++) {
    subjectArray.push(subjectJSON[i].value);
  }
  return true;
});
```

Also, there is no `int` in JavaScript.